# Hash bangs for facebook like and twitter buttons

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I currently have a wordpress site that loads in posts in an ajax modal, with its own hash bang (#!) url. Each post has a Facebook like and twitter button, but whenever I try to post the url for the post using the either button it does not post the hash bang url. Facebook uses a very long code, where as twitter just uses the base url of the site without the hash bang. Is there a way to output the proper url with hash bang?

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: This is problematic. URL Hash fragments are not really accessible on the serverside. Even if you were to post the actual URL (including hash fragments) into Facebook, the preview wouldn't be able to give you correct data because Facebook's servers wouldn't get to see the AJAX post derived from the Hash fragment.